# How can you condition the colour of the lines in aggplot2 plot according to the value of the axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

With {ggplot2} I would like to colour the lines of my graph according to the value contained in the axes.
As a bonus, it would be great to be able to add a legend for the colours.

I tried this :

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

get_label_color <- function(label) {
  if (endsWith(label, "with csv")) {
    "red"
  } else if (endsWith(label, "with polars")) {
    "blue"
  } else {
    "black" 
  }
}

bmk <- microbenchmark(
  "A with csv" = iris %>% count(Species),
  "B with polars" = nrow(iris),
  "C with csv" = sort(names(iris)),
  "D with polars" = iris %>% filter(Species=="setosa"),
  times = 5
) %>% 
  mutate(
    mycolor = sapply(as.character(expr),get_label_color)
  )


autoplot(bmk) +
  labs(title = "polars vs others") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = bmk$mycolor)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to get different results to you, but in this case (a ggplot created with `microbenchmark:::autoplot.microbenchmark`), the key is to add `aes(color = expr)` to your plot. This then allows you to specify whichever colors you like to the lines via `scale_color_manual`:

```r
autoplot(bmk) +
  labs(title = "polars vs others") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = c('blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red'))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  aes(color = expr) +
  scale_color_manual('operation', values = c('blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the rows ending in with csv do not have the same colour in the plot (one is red and the other blue)

Comment: @DamienDotta but you can change them to whatever you want - that's my point. See my update for an example

Answer (score 2):

You can hack the `autoplot()`, try this:

```r
autoplot(bmk) +
  # originally `stat_y_density(aes(color = expr))`
  aes(color = expr) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = setNames(
      sapply(as.character(bmk$expr),get_label_color),
      as.character(bmk$expr)
    )
  ) +
  labs(title = "polars vs others") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, +1. However, you don't need `stat_y_density`. You can add a bare `aes(color = expr)` to the plot.

Comment: Thanks can I get the labels colored ?

Comment: Yeah, you can see the example figure.